# Adding multiple taxes to invoice object in quickbooks

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm able to add a tax to my Invoice objects on quickbooks via the following json.

```json
"TxnTaxDetail": {
  "TxnTaxCodeRef": {
    "value": "2"
  }, 
  "TotalTax": 26.82, 
  "TaxLine": [
    {
      "DetailType": "TaxLineDetail", 
      "Amount": 26.82, 
      "TaxLineDetail": {
        "NetAmountTaxable": 335.25, 
        "TaxPercent": 8, 
        "TaxRateRef": {
          "value": "3"
        }, 
        "PercentBased": true
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

I'd like to be able to add a second tax (which has a difference tax code ID and rate ID) to the invoice.

I've tried the following, but this doesn't work:

```json
"TxnTaxDetail": [{
  "TxnTaxCodeRef": {
    "value": "2"
  }, 
  "TotalTax": 26.82, 
  "TaxLine": [
    {
      "DetailType": "TaxLineDetail", 
      "Amount": 26.82, 
      "TaxLineDetail": {
        "NetAmountTaxable": 335.25, 
        "TaxPercent": 8, 
        "TaxRateRef": {
          "value": "3"
        }, 
        "PercentBased": true
      }
    }
  ]
}, 
{
  "TxnTaxCodeRef": {
    "value": "3"
  }, 
  "TotalTax": 30.82, 
  "TaxLine": [
    {
      "DetailType": "TaxLineDetail", 
      "Amount": 30.82, 
      "TaxLineDetail": {
        "NetAmountTaxable": 335.25, 
        "TaxPercent": 8, 
        "TaxRateRef": {
          "value": "4"
        }, 
        "PercentBased": true
      }
    }
  ]
}, 

]
```